# Multi class array modification

Tags: java, arrays, oop, static, access-modifiers

3 questions in three days (I wish I could fix my problems alone) and today is still about my Sudoku project. I'm working on building a Sudoku game in Java and am working with other people who have programmed various parts of the project and right now we are trying to join together the Sudoku solver class with the JFrame class which makes it all pretty (Or it will at one point) but right now I'm having an issue with the way my 2D arrays are working (more like aren't). Below is the code where I call the solver and feed it into a lot of methods to do things:

```
public class FenetreGrille extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

public static int [][] NOMBRES_DEBUT;
public static int [][] GRILLE_MODIF = new int[9][9];
public int [][] GRILLE_FINALE = new int[9][9];

public static final int TAILLE = 9;                                 
public static int TAILLECASE = 60;
public static int COTEGRILLE ;

public FenetreGrille(int [][] t){
    NOMBRES_DEBUT = t;
    GRILLE_MODIF = NOMBRES_DEBUT;
    GRILLE_FINALE = NOMBRES_DEBUT;
    COTEGRILLE = TAILLE * TAILLECASE;

    SudokuBackTrack sbt = new SudokuBackTrack(GRILLE_FINALE);
    // Here is the problem ^^^^^
    // More code below that shouldn't be important...
}
```

And here is the SudokuBackTrack class:

```
public class SudokuBackTrack{

public static int[][] grille;
public static int[][] grilleResolu;
public static int[][] grillePos;

public static boolean[][] existeSurLigne = new boolean[9][9];
public static boolean[][] existeSurColonne = new boolean[9][9];
public static boolean[][] existeSurBloc = new boolean[9][9];

public final static int taille = 9;

public static ArrayList<Case> valParCase;

public SudokuBackTrack(int[][] t) {
    grille = t;
    grilleResolu = grille;
    valParCase = listeValPossibles(grilleResolu);
    tableauxExistence(grilleResolu);
    backtracking(0, grilleResolu);
}

public static ArrayList<Case> listeValPossibles(int[][] temp) {
    ArrayList<Case> t = new ArrayList<Case>();

    for (int i=0; i<9; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<9; j++){
            if(temp[i][j] == 0) {
                int pos = i*taille+j;
                t.add(valeursPossibles(pos, temp));
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(t);
    return t;
}

public static Case valeursPossibles(int pos, int[][] t) {
    int i = pos/9;
    int j = pos%9;
    int valPossibles = 9;

    for(int s=1; s<=9; s++) {
        if(!absentSurLigne(s, i, t) || !absentSurColonne(s, j, t) || !absentDansBloc(s, i, j, t)) {
            valPossibles--;
        }
    }
    Case a = new Case(pos, valPossibles);
    return a;
}

public static boolean absentSurLigne(int k, int i, int[][] t) {
    for (int j=0; j < 9; j++) {
        if (t[i][j] == k) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean absentSurColonne(int k, int j, int[][] t) {
    for (int i=0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (t[i][j] == k) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean absentDansBloc(int k, int i, int j, int[][] t) {
    int _i = i-(i%3);   // ou encore : _i = 3*(i/3);
    int _j = j-(j%3);   // ou encore : _j = 3*(j/3);
    for (i=_i; i < _i+3; i++) {
        for (j=_j; j < _j+3; j++) {
            if (t[i][j] == k) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void tableauxExistence(int[][] t) {
    for (int i=0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < 9; j++) {
            existeSurLigne[i][j] = existeSurColonne[i][j] = existeSurBloc[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    int k;
    for (int i=0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < 9; j++) {
            if ((k = t[i][j]) != 0) {
                existeSurLigne[i][k-1] = existeSurColonne[j][k-1] = existeSurBloc[3*(i/3)+(j/3)][k-1] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static boolean backtracking(int index, int[][] t) {

    if(index == valParCase.size()) {
        return true;
    }

    int i = (valParCase.get(index).position)/9;
    int j = (valParCase.get(index).position)%9;

    for(int k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
        if(!existeSurLigne[i][k] && !existeSurColonne[j][k] && !existeSurBloc[3*(i/3)+(j/3)][k]){
            // Ajoute k aux valeurs enregistrées
            existeSurLigne[i][k] = existeSurColonne[j][k] = existeSurBloc[3*(i/3)+(j/3)][k] = true;

            if(backtracking(index+1, t)){
                // Ecrit le choix valide dans la grille
                t[i][j] = k+1;
                return true;
            }
            // Supprime k des valeurs enregistrées
            existeSurLigne[i][k] = existeSurColonne[j][k] = existeSurBloc[3*(i/3)+(j/3)][k] = false;
        }
    }

    t[i][j] = 0;
    return false;
}
```

As mentioned above, my problem is that when I create an instance of my SudokuBackTrack class using the 2D Array GRILLE_FINALE, all my 2D Arrays NOMBRES_DEBUT, GRILLE_MODIF and GRILLE_FINALE become solved Sudoku grids whereas all I want is for GRILLE_FINALE to become the solved version, not all 3. I've tried debugging the codes but I haven't found anything and since it's a mixture of codes from different people, I don't know how they each created their parts. I've modified the attribute types and tried all sorts of fancy things but non worked and I'm out of ideas and mainly time... Thanks in advance and sorry for the huge question and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're placing the same instance of the 2D array into NOMBRES_DEBUT, GRILLE_MODIF, GRILLE_FINALE. I think what you're looking to do is to place a **copy** NOMBRES_DEBUT into GRILLE_MODIF and GRILLE_FINALE.

They way you have it set up now, whever you make a modification to any of the 3 arrays, you will end up modifying all 3 because all 3 point to the same array in memory.

Comment: So should I create a new 2D array, give that array the values of int[][] t in the constructor and then give the others the value of that new one ?

Comment: Try searching  google for 'copy array java' you should be able to find a few useful results to give you a simple solution.

Comment: IT WORKED !!!  I completely forgot the basics of java honestly with this. Thanks a lot !